# preg_replace_callback - compilation failed

Tags: php, regex

## code

```
$lang_string = preg_replace_callback('/[LINK:([^:]+):([^:]+)](.+)[\/LINK]/m', function($match){
    return '<a href="'.get_subpage_url($match[1], $match[2]).'">'.$match[3].'</a>';
}, $lang_string);
```

## Find

```
[LINK:functions:bankimport]Bankimport[/LINK]
```

## Replace with

```
'<a href="'.get_subpage_url('functions', 'bankimport').'">Bankimport</a>'
```

## Error

```
preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a special meta charcater in regex. You need to escape   `[`  to match a literal `[` symbol or otherwise regex engine would consider it as a start of a character class.

```
\[LINK:([^:]+):([^:]+)](.+)\[\/LINK]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hL6vE6/3)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this here right now, but I think you have to escape the brackets around the LINK-Tags:

```
$lang_string = preg_replace_callback('/\[LINK:([^:]+):([^:]+)\](.+)\[\/LINK\]/m', function($match){
    return '<a href="'.get_subpage_url($match[1], $match[2]).'">'.$match[3].'</a>';
}, $lang_string);
```